# symbolic link apache modules

Tags: apache, unix, apache2, symlink, httpd.conf

My default apache modules are currently within /usr/bin. The modules i have generated however are within /home/user/platform/lib. Within the httpd.conf file i have added the two modules as per example:

```
LoadModule rtb_module lib/mod_rtb.so
LoadModule win_module lib/mod_win.so
```

However when loading the modules i see errors because the two mentioned modules reside somewhere else (in this case /home/user/platform/lib). Is there a way to symlink these two modules within the httpd.conf file?

many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using *ln -s* created a symbolic link to the necessary path, resolving the issue